# How to produce multiple circles with this HTML canvas codebase?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

http://codepen.io/jkoller90/pen/ZLwqXw

What I'm trying to do is set a condition such that clicking on this image will cause a circle to remain there permanently. At this point, the code only allows for circles to appear on click.

I'm pretty new to canvas, though. Do I need to add layers to the canvas? Or maybe overlap new canvases on top of what I've got?

What I've tried so far is using .unbind on the window object. This is in response to:

```
$(window).on('mousedown', this.showControl.bind(this)); //on line 34.
```

It produces one image which is great, but I can't repeat the circle animations. I've also considered creating a function that exists outside of the prototype chain in case it's a scope issue.

```
function circleUI() {
  this.mousedown = false;
  this.canvasEl = $('#canvas');
  this.canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
  this.ctx = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
  this.circ = Math.PI * 2;
  this.quart = Math.PI / 2;
  this.options = {
  canvasWidth: 400,
  strokeWidth: 3.0,
  strokeColor: 'rgba(192,192,192,1)',
  y: {
  radius: 40,
  strokeColor: 'rgba(192, 192, 192, 1)'
  }
 this.ctx.lineWidth = this.options.strokeWidth;
 this.imd = this.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, this.options.canvasWidth,this.options.canvasWidth);
 this.init();
 this.draw();
}
};
```

The original code drew two arcs which connected. I adjusted the colors and left it so I could focus on the functionality. Thank you if you can offer some advice!

Comment: Do you mean that you want to keep the existing click and drag functionality, but then leave the circle in place at the end of the drag rather than making it disappear?

Comment: @nnnnnn Exactly. I'm thinking I need to append canvas elements